# Set Default Layout Page Using REST API Javascript

Tags: rest, page-layout, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am developing a SharePoint-Hosted add-in which bascially provisions a custom page layout to the master page gallery of an publishing site collection. After this is done I want to make this layout as default page layout of my wiki pages. Is there a way to do this with using the REST API or CSOM/JSOM?

[image: this ui action via rest api?]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about REST but it can be achieved through CSOM

```
// The page layout is defined by its filename
var filename = "NewsArticlePage.aspx";
setDefaultPageLayout(filename, onSuccess, onFailure);

// The page layouts are defined by an array of filenames
var filenames = ["NewsArticlePage.aspx"];
setAvailablePageLayouts(filenames, onSuccess, onFailure);

// The web templates are defined by their long name,
//the guid is that of the feature which deploys the web template
var webTemplates = ["{BDACFFF5-05DF-4446-9907-B4C39F15F1D7}#WT_VanitySite"];
setAvailableWebTemplates(webTemplates, onSuccess, onFailure);
```

Comment: i found this code at this website as well http://paulryan.com.au/2014/setting-default-page-layout-via-csom/ but not sure how to use the method "setDefaultPageLayout".

Comment: See this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92910/setting-page-layout-using-jsom

Comment: this link is unfortunately not what i'm looking for. I look for something like this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25796/possible-to-set-the-default-page-layout-for-a-site-using-powershell